# Kill error process if it appears in window 7 automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am running some automation script. During some point in measurement one of the process (iMPACT in my case) gives fails. This in turn invokes window7 to generate error dialogue box. 
How can I automatically close or kill this process if it appears in the middle of experiment.
I have attached the screenshot of the error that appears during test execution.[image]

Comment: I think if you were bound and determined to do this in batch, I think your best attempt would be to run a batch file running a `FOR` loop with `TASKLIST /FI "STATUS EQ RUNNING` piping (`|`) to a `FINDSTR` looking for your specific task, if it's found, terminate the process. Although I'd personally just run an external app for such a mundane purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a registry setting called ErrorMode that controls what happens when these types of errors occur.  The default is to show the dialog boxes but you can have the system write the errors to the event log instead.  Just be aware that it's a system wide setting so it affects all programs.   The valid values are:

```
 0     Errors are serialized and wait for a response.

 1     If the error does not come from the system, then the system
       continues in normal operating mode. If the error comes from the
       system, then it is written to the system log; no user
       intervention is required and dialog boxes are not displayed.

 2     The error is written to the system log; the dialog box is not
       displayed.
```

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/124873

Comment: Thanks JJF. That did the charm.